# How to create a data-structure with such property

Tags: algorithm

I have to design a data structure such that I have an array A having size N, i.e. `A[1],A[1],A[2],...A[n]`.I have to handle two types of queries (there are total M queries):

1. Add 1 to range from I to j in the array A
2. Find Kth smallest element in the array A

Given `1<=N,M<=200000.`

First I think of square-root decomposition by sorting each bucket but Unable to update partial ranges that fall in different buckets. Can you suggest how to go about it?

I want some `O(N*Log(N))` or `O(N*SQRT(N))` complexity.

Comment: Anything known about the initial state of the array?

Comment: Yes, whole array is given to you

Comment: Has question body been changed in grace period? (Because I thought about max/min, not k-smallest)

Comment: @MBo no, question is same

Comment: OK, so will delete my answer because Fenwick tree does not allow to retrieve k-smallest quickly

Comment: Is range of values limited?

Comment: I think I did not fully understand the question. With a simple array you can do operation 1 in O(N) and operation 2 in an average of O(N) (for example with quick select)

Comment: @MBo ranges 1<=i,j<=N

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a fairly typical competitive programming problem. I think I have a solution, although it's a bit ugly - maybe you can improve it.

We're going to use square root decomposition (see [link](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/sqrt_decomposition.html) if you're not familiar with this method) at the core of our solution. For each block we are going to keep: values of elements as is (let's name it `A`), number of additions to the entire block (one integer, let's name it `extra`) and `IND` - sorted array of block indices by value (e.g. if block elements were [4, 2, 5], the indices array would be [1, 0, 2]). Now let's go over how this allows us to solve the problem and what the complexity would be.

### Initialization

For each of `sqrt(N)` blocks we will have to sort it (`sqrt(N) * log(sqrt(N))` per block), to get the initial indices array, leading to `sqrt(N) * sqrt(N) * log(sqrt(N)) = N * log(N)` initialization complexity.

### Add 1 to range (l, r)

Proceed just like with a regular sqrt-decomposition update. For each block fully inside the range we are going to increment the `extra` counter. A crucial observation is that the relative order of elements doesn't change, so our work here is done. For blocks that are partially inside the update range, we do the following: update `A` by incrementing appropriate elements by 1, regenerate `IND` array by doing sort. Note that there are at most two partial update blocks. The total complexity for "full" block update in `O(1)` and there are `sqrt(N)` of them. Partial update is `sqrt(N) * log(sqrt(N)) = sqrt(N) * log(N)`, giving the total update complexity of `sqrt(N) * log(N)`. There are M queries, so at worst these updates will contribute `M * sqrt(N) * log(N)`.

### Find K-th smallest element

Let's figure out how to find the number of elements in our array less than some value `L`. To do that, for each block we are going to do a binary search over `IND` array. When we have some index `idx` from that array, the actual value to use is `A[idx] + extra`, where `A` and `extra` come from that block. This procedure allows us to get the number of elements greater than `L` inside each block. Afterwards, we just sum results for each block. To process one block we have to spend `log(sqrt(N)) = log(N)` on binary search, and there are `sqrt(N)` blocks, leading to `sqrt(N) * log(N)` complexity.

To get K-th smallest element, we are going to do another binary search for the possible answer (common technique in competitive programming), we are going to binary search between smallest and largest possible answer (e.g. min element and max element plus `M`). Let's denote this range as `C`. At each step we check how many elements are less than our current guess, and when we find the K-th smallest element, we'll have the answer. Let me know if you need more elaboration of this step.

The final complexity becomes `log(C) * sqrt(N) * log(N)`, and there can be M queries, making it `M * log(C) * sqrt(N) * log(N)`. If initial array is all zeroes or has values in `0` to `M` range, this would be `M * log(M) * sqrt(N) * log(N)`. Or you can choose to treat `C` as constant (which is not quite right).

I'm pretty sure one of the `log`'s can be shaved-off, but that is left to the reader as an exercise :)

Comment: I solved it exactly this way,but My question is to solve it in O(M*sqrt(N)) or O(Mlog(N)) time.